# Can the mockito3 mockConstruction make stub on 'new File'

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I see Mockito has also support mock construction:

https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.11.2/org/mockito/Mockito.html#49
https://rieckpil.de/mock-java-constructors-and-their-object-creation-with-mockito/

but I can't make stub on construction of File:

```
try (MockedConstruction<File> ignored = Mockito.mockConstruction(File.class,
      (context) -> {
          Log.info("new file: {} in {},{},{}", context.getCount(), context.arguments(), context.constructor());
          return Mockito.withSettings().defaultAnswer(CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
       })) {
       File stub = new File("test");
}
```

It will java.lang.StackOverflowError for

```
at java.base/java.io.File.exists(File.java:816)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at java.base/java.io.File.exists(File.java:816)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at java.base/java.io.File.exists(File.java:816)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:642)
```

Do you know how to mock the 'new' File class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this running by adding following code in the test:

```java
 static class Foo implements Serializable, Comparable<Foo> {
    String method() {
        return "foo";
    }

    public int compareTo(Foo o) {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Test
void testFile() {
    try (MockedConstruction mocked = mockConstruction(Foo.class)) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        when(foo.method()).thenReturn("bar");
        assertEquals("bar", foo.method());
        verify(foo).method();
    }
    
    try (MockedConstruction<File> ignored = Mockito.mockConstruction(File.class,
            (context) -> {
                Log.info("new file: {} in {},{},{}", context.getCount(), context.arguments(), context.constructor());
                return Mockito.withSettings().defaultAnswer(CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
            })) {
        File stub = new File("test");
    }
}
```

IMHO a bug in Mockito / ByteBuddy

Comment: Thanks for you test. Could you tell me how to report this issue for mockito?

Comment: I added my finding under the bug you posted: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2342

Comment: Thanks.  it seemed that there is no solution for it till now.